# iOS localization crash

Tags: ios, localization

Have a really weird one here.
The app has two targets, just to be able to change the icon in one store.  They share the code totally and are localized into a number of languages.

If I set my phone to Swedish, one of the targets crash on launch...

> 2012-02-08 21:20:39.488 isengua-en[25341:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key testContentView.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x30caa8bf 0x37e4f1e5 0x30caa5f5 0x37cd5333 0x37cd4e33 0x37caef19 0x30c09803 0x30c0a491 0x32eb84bf 0x32e289cb 0x32d07ea1 0x32c7d78b 0x32ca1f51 0x32c666a5 0x32d290e5 0x32c6ee51 0x32c6ee6d 0x32c6ee6d 0x32c6ecff 0x32c6ecdb 0x37e7 0x32c7c7eb 0x32c763bd 0x32c44921 0x32c443bf 0x32c43d2d 0x3382fe13 0x30c7e553 0x30c7e4f5 0x30c7d343 0x30c004dd 0x30c003a5 0x32c75457 0x32c72743 0x32a7 0x2cf0)
>   terminate called throwing an exception(gdb)

Any other language and it is just fine.
I have duplicated the target that is OK and renamed it, and all the other stuff.

All localizations are done by NSLocalizedString.

Any idea anyone?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case anyone else get the same problem at some stage.
The solution was to delete the app from my iPhone and build again.  Obviously something got left over between the builds that caused it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you duplicated your nib files for the different locales?

It looks like the Swedish version of one of the nib files (can't tell which one from the error, maybe MainWindow.xib?) has a binding to an outlet called testContentView that you've probably deleted since you branched it for localisation.

To fix it, open up the nib and check in the Inspector for any broken bindings, or just copy the working nib from one of the other locales and replace the one in the swedish locale folder.